# Cannot run powermock due to "Unexpected exception" and "org.mockito.exceptions.misusing" errors

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito, powermock

I have Java version 11, **JUnit** version **4.13.1** and try to apply `powermock` for my Unit Test. I added necessary libraries as mentioned on [this](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito-2-Maven) page:

***JUnit 4.4 or above:***

```
<properties>
    <powermock.version>2.0.2</powermock.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
      <version>${powermock.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
      <version>${powermock.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Then update my Unit Test as shown below:

***DemoUnitTest:***

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Locale.class)
public class DemoUnitTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private DemoServiceImpl demoService;

    @Test(expected = EntityNotFoundException.class)
    public void test_PowerMock() {
        String countryCodeUpper = countryCode.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH);

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Locale.class);
        BDDMockito.given(Locale.getISOCountries()).willReturn(new String[]{});

        demoService.create(countryCode);
    }
}
```

So, where is mistake?

Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected<com.mycompany.common.domain.exception.EntityNotFoundException> but was<org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException>

    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.handleException(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:380)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.handleException(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:126)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.handleInvocationTargetException(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:353)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:331)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:89)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:97)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:298)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:218)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:160)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:134)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:136)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:117)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:221)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: Argument should be a mock, but is: class java.lang.Class
    at com.mycompany.core.service.impl.unit.CountryServiceImplTest.test_PowerMock(CountryServiceImplTest.java:191)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:89)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:97)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Can you add exception with stack trace?

Comment: @Alex Though I haven't tried with Java 11 , can you try using  PowerMockito.when(Locale.getISOCountries()).thenReturn(new String[]{});

Comment: I tried also with it as mentioned on documentation, but still the same problem. I am trying to use via something like that `when(SSLContext.getInstance(anyString())).thenAnswer((Answer<SSLContext>) invocation -> sslContextMock);` But not sure it works

Comment: @talex I added stacktrace, any help pls?

Comment: @talex Chico, are you there?

Answer (score 0):

**Change your `@PrepareForTest(Locale.class)` to `@PrepareForTest(DemoServiceImpl.class)`.**

[Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html), from the `java.util` package, is a *system class*. PowerMockRunner cannot intercept its loading because Java has already loaded it. As such, you have to [use the special rule for mocking system classes](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mock-System) in which you invert the normal rule:

> Normally you would prepare the class that contains the static methods (let's call it X) you like to mock but because it's impossible for PowerMock to prepare a system class for testing so another approach has to be taken. So instead of preparing X you prepare the class that calls the static methods in X!

This makes *some* sense: `@PrepareForTest` indicates which classes PowerMock should intercept and bytecode-rewrite. Because you can't intercept and bytecode-rewrite Locale, the next best thing is to intercept and bytecode-rewrite your system under test so it calls PowerMock's rewritten Locale instead of Java's Locale.

---

Generally, mocking your system-under-test is seen as a bad practice, but this is a bit of an exception: As long as you're not actually mocking your own system under test, this is more like creating a test seam in your class. There's no danger of accidentally testing against your mock behavior instead of testing your intended system. That said, you might consider a refactor:

- You could save `Locale.getISOCountries()` to a ["visible for testing"](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/annotations/VisibleForTesting.html) field that you replace in your test, or make it an optional constructor argument that defers to `Locale.getISOCountries()` when absent.
- You could extract the call to `Locale.getISOCountries()` to a lambda (e.g. `Supplier<String[]>`) and likewise make it a visible field or optional constructor argument.
- You could extract the call into an overridable method on DemoServiceImpl and override it in your test, though that also runs the risk of a blurred boundary between implementation and test code.