# Unit Test: Should I use null or Optional.empty() in thenReturn()?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-data-jpa

I test a `Spring Data JPA` method as shown below:

```
Optional<Country> findByUuid(final UUID uuid);
```

When I write Unit Test for this method, I can test it by using a return value of `null` or `Optional.empty()` in `thenReturn()` method.

```
when(demoRepository.findByUuid(uuid)).thenReturn(null);

// or

when(demoRepository.findByUuid(uuid)).thenReturn(Optional.empty());
```

So, which one is more proper way for this?

Comment: If that method declares its return value to be Optional then you must assume it will never return null. Return Optional.empty()

Comment: Why do you use `Optional` as the return type? Right: because you never ever want to return an literal `null`.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle It is not my choice actually, the architecture :(

Comment: What about null `String[]` values as mentioned on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69394651/cannot-run-powermock-due-to-unexpected-exception-and-org-mockito-exceptions-m ?Any idea about that (I also have similar problem).

Comment: *"It is not my choice actually"* **---** **1.** It's not me you need to explain anything... ;o) **2.** did nobody tell you that returning   literal `null` is the most common cause for `NullPionterException`s and shoul'd be avoided at any chance?

Answer (score 3):

The latter.

When a method returns Optional, for all intents and purposes there's an implicit assumption that it's not nullable. If callers had to check *not only* for nullity but also for presence/absence of a value in the Optional, all code which called a method returning Optional would be horrendously verbose.

No client code should be checking whether an Optional return is null. Therefore using the former is overwhelmingly likely to produce null pointer exceptions.

Comment: Agreed. The whole point of `Optional` is that you _don't_ return null, but `Optional.empty()`.

Comment: What about null `String[]` values as mentioned on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69394651/cannot-run-powermock-due-to-unexpected-exception-and-org-mockito-exceptions-m ?Any idea about that (I also have similar problem).

Comment: @Robert So that I'm clear, is your question that if a method returns String[], should you return null or an empty array? For any method that returns a collection - whether it's an array, a Collection (or List/Set/ArrayList etc.), or an Optional (you can think of it as a collection of size 1) - then you should *always* prefer an empty collection over null, in both your real code and in your mocks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your useful explanations. If you have any experience, could you pls have a look at that question? I also tried to use powermock, but get the same error as mentioned on that page.